# Undefined array key pageType when login, even if it's added to a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to log in and then redirect to a custom page, based on user type. My problem is that when I'm pressing the login button, on the console I get that that I have a **Undefined array key pageType**, and I don't understand why... If I'm for example on teacher page, I set  `$_SESSION['pageType'] = 'teacher';`
This my login.html page:

```
<img class="wave" src="img/wave.png">
    <div class="container_main" onsubmit="redirect();">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="img/bg.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="login-content">
            <form onsubmit="redirect();"> 
                
                <img src="img/avatar.svg">
                <h2 class="title">Quiz Website</h2>
                <div class="input-div one">
                   <div class="i">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="div">
                        <input type="text" class="input" id="enterID" placeholder="Username">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-div pass">
                   <div class="i"> 
                        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                   </div>
                   <div class="div form-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" required/>
                   </div>

                </div>
                <a href="page/registration.php">Don't have an account?</a>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="page/forget-password.php" class="ForgetPwd">Trouble logging in?</a>
                    </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" onclick="login();" readonly >
                <div class="error-message" id="errorMessage"></div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

This is checklogin.js:

```
function login() {
    var enterID = document.getElementById("enterID").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ((password != "") && (enterID != "")) {
        var info = "?enterID=" + enterID + "&password=" + password;
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                async: true,
                url: "php/login.php" + info,
                success: function (respond) {
                    if (respond == "admin") {
                        window.location.href = "page/admin-system-management.php";
                    } else if (respond == "student") {
                        window.location.href = "page/student-dashboard.php";
                    } else if (respond == "teacher") {
                        window.location.href = "page/teacher-dashboard.php";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = respond;
                    }


                }
            });
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = "Please fill in all the fields.";
    }
}

function redirect() {
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: "php/redirect.php",
            success: function (respond) {

                if (respond != "not logged.") {
                    if (respond == "admin") {
                        window.location.href = "page/admin-system-management.php";
                    } else if (respond == "student") {
                        window.location.href = "page/student-dashboard.php";
                    } else if (respond == "teacher") {
                        window.location.href = "page/teacher-dashboard.php";
                    }
                }
                console.log(respond)
            }
        });
}
```

And this is my redirect.php file:

```
<?php
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION["type"])){
        if ($_SESSION["type"] != $_SESSION["pageType"]){
            $alert_message = "You cannot access this page using your account!";
            $link = "../login.html";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert_message'); window.setTimeout(function(){ if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='admin'){ window.location.href = '../page/admin-system-management.php';} else if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='student'){ window.location.href = '../page/student-dashboard.php';} else if ('".$_SESSION["type"]."'=='teacher'){ window.location.href = '../page/teacher-dashboard.php';}  }, 0);</script>";
        }

    } else {
        $alert_message = "Your login period has expired! Please login again!";
        $link = "../login.html";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert_message'); window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = '$link'; }, 0);</script>";
    }

?>
```

What I suspect is that the redirect() function it's not even loaded, so that's why I think I'm getting this error... Sometimes I'm seeing ,,XHR failed loading: GET"
I modified a code in order to have another login.html page, this is my old login.html code:

```
<body class="jumbotron vertical-center" onload="redirect();">
    <div class="container login-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 login-form mx-auto">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <h6>Don't have an account?<a href="page/registration.php" class=""> Register</a></h6>
                <form>
                    <div class="error-message" id="errorMessage"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="enterID" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your User ID *" value="" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password *" value="" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Login" onclick="login();" readonly />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="page/forget-password.php" class="ForgetPwd">Trouble logging in?</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you get an error message, it helps if you post the full error message and point us to where it happens. Now we need to read through all your code and guess where it happens. You need to help us help you.

Comment: I would also recommend that you use POST to send authentication details. If you send them as GET, the URL, including the user credential, will be a part of the browser history for anyone to view.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I get the warning at the checklogin.js redirect function. It says that on redirect.php,line 6 it can't find the key pageType. So basically, I just need to switch from GET to POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inside redirect() function add this line at the start.
   This will stop the forms default action of redirecting/refreshing the page

   `event.preventDefault();`

Then your redirect function / respond variable should work

2. If you return this from php it will be ignored by javascript

   `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>code here\</script>";`
3. To make your redirect.php easier to debug output the data as a json encoded array instead of a string that way you can view/test more data.
   inside redirect.php try add this code straight after the session_start() line just as a first test

```
$data = [
 'session' => $_SESSION,
 'response' => 'place your response here',
];
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, on my localhost it perfectly worked, but I still have some problems on my Hostinger subdomain, and I don't understand why.. It doesn't want to load the login script

Comment: does it say error 500 on the server? or something else. paste the error here and i will check it

Comment: Nope, it just don't want to execute my redirect function...

Comment: Is your server online? you can paste the url here if it is so we can see the issue

Comment: I get  XHR failed loading: GET

Comment: It looks like there is a problem in the bootstrap file, this might be preventing the rest of the javascript from loading. try upgrading it to the latest version - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/ if you are using google chrome right click and goto to inspect, then click on the console tab and reload the page to see the error i am talking about

Comment: still not loading, jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: GET

Comment: Your server code is different to your local code, check the <form> tag it is missing the redirect() function

Comment: On localhost I don't have errors, while on hostinger I get You cannot access this page using your account!

Comment: it looks like its working fine now. check the console log after you click login/submit. Now in your redirect.php response change the response to echo 'Your login period has expired! Please login again!'; instead of returning javascript. You will need to write the javascript inside the javascript file then capture the text/message response from the server and pass it to alert that way

Comment: You should probably try the echo json_encode($data); example i wrote above for your redirect.php response. by returning an array of data will make it easier to debug the php responses

Comment: can you please edit the answer for the page redirect.php?  I also have that string on timeout-redirect.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is the update i think you need.

redirect.php

```
<?php

if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

// you can change this line to this once you have debugged your code - $data = [];
$data = ['session' => $_SESSION];

// place code here to get the user type from the database
// then use $_SESSION['type'] = '{database response}';

if(!isset($_SESSION['type']))
{
    $_SESSION['type'] = null;
}

switch($_SESSION['type']) {
    case 'admin':
        header('Location: /page/admin-system-management.php'); // this is the php way to redirect
        break;

    case 'student':
        header('Location: /page/student-dashboard.php');
        break;

    case 'teacher':
        header('Location: /page/teacher-dashboard.php');
        break;

    default:
        $data['alert_message'] = 'Your login period has expired! Please login again!';
        
}
echo json_encode($data);
exit;

?>
```

Javascript redirect function

```
    function redirect() {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: "php/redirect.php",
            success: function (response) {

                console.log(response);

                if(response.alert_message) {
                    alert(response.alert_message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I made a few more updates so check this version above now which is the latest version :)

Comment: However i have no idea where you are getting the $_SESSION['type'] from. I am guessing you will need to check the database for that value.

Comment: also i noticed your bootstrap changed back to 4.1 so double check that if you did not mean to do that.

Comment: So, I have a working solution. I've used your first solution and then I've changed a little bit the redirect.php in order to work. Now I only have some problems with retreving certain fields from db

Comment: create a new post on stackoverflow with your updated code/problem and add the link to the comments here

Comment: Also its good to hear your original problem is solved